"it" for the role of the chaser in games
A chosen player in the game of "Marco Polo" who is trying to find other players is called "it". A similar game of tag also uses the word "it" for the chaser.
Is the origin of this usage known?
Is said player called anything other than "it" (e.g. chaser)?
Are there other games in which there is the role called "it"?
